# How can get back the saved password in my workstation?

Tags: windows, security, passwords, credentials

As you may know, when trying to connect to a remote share secured with a password, Windows may pop up an input box asking for login credentials. If I select the "remember password" option, the password is stored somewhere for seamless login on the next connection - it doesn't ask for a password any more.

Where are these passwords saved? Sometimes I might want to delete the saved password so that on the next login Windows will ask me for credentials again.

Answer (score 5):

run `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr` in a command line

Answer (score 0):

NirSoft's [Network Password Recovery](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html).